# Multi-Statement Table Valued Function with Table Variables

Tags: sql-server

I might just need assistance with the best type of procedure to use to get what i want but here is what i am trying to do.
I need to return a table which is derived from multiple table variables the catch is that i need to call this table from outside of SQL so cannot use the Table Variables directly. So I have tried using table-valued functions. If there is a way to do all this in a view without using table variables to start with then even better but I cannot figure out a way to do that.
So ideally i would like a single SELECT statement that is called from outside SQL that pulls the results back from the following statement.

```
SELECT        Master.id, Master.SPName, DashCopyName, SRECopyName, TapeCopyName, DRCopyName

FROM            @Master AS Master LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @TapeCopy AS TapeCopy ON Master.SPName = TapeCopy.SPName AND Master.id = TapeCopy.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @DRCopy AS DRCopy ON Master.SPName = DRCopy.SPName AND Master.id = DRCopy.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @SRECopy AS SRECopy ON Master.SPName = SRECopy.SPName AND Master.id = SRECopy.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @DashCopy AS DashCopy ON Master.SPName = DashCopy.SPName AND Master.id = DashCopy.id
                     WHERE Master.id = @sp
```

So here is the entire table-valued function i have so far:

```
ALTER FUNCTION StoragePolicyCopies(@sp int)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE (
id int,
SPName char(30), 
DashCopyName char(50), 
SRECopyName char(50), 
TapeCopyName char(50), 
DRCopyName char(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DashCopy TABLE (
SPName char(30),
DashCopyName char(50),
id int)
INSERT INTO @DashCopy (SPName, DashCopyName, id)
SELECT        archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS DashCopyName, archGroup.id
FROM            commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
WHERE        (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_Dash_Copy%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')

DECLARE @DRCopy TABLE (
SPName char(30),
DRCopyName char(50),
id int)
INSERT INTO @DRCopy (SPName, DRCopyName, id)
SELECT        archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS DRCopyName, archGroup.id
FROM            commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
WHERE        (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_DR%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')

DECLARE @SRECopy TABLE (
SPName char(30),
SRECopyName char(50),
id int)
INSERT INTO @SRECopy (SPName, SRECopyName, id)
SELECT        archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS SRECopyName, archGroup.id
FROM            commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup LEFT OUTER JOIN
            commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
WHERE        (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_Recover%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')

DECLARE @TapeCopy TABLE (
SPName char(30),
TapeCopyName char(50),
id int)
INSERT INTO @TapeCopy (SPName, TapeCopyName, id)
SELECT        archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS TapeCopyName, archGroup.id
FROM            commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup LEFT OUTER JOIN
            commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
WHERE        (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_Monthly_Tape%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')

DECLARE @Master TABLE (
SPName char(30),
id int)
INSERT INTO @Master (SPName, id)
SELECT        name AS SPName, id
FROM            commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup
WHERE        flags = 36 AND name NOT LIKE '%SEED%' AND name NOT LIKE '%ICO%'

INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
SELECT        Master.id, Master.SPName, DashCopyName, SRECopyName, TapeCopyName, DRCopyName
FROM            @Master AS Master LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @TapeCopy AS TapeCopy ON Master.SPName = TapeCopy.SPName AND Master.id = TapeCopy.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @DRCopy AS DRCopy ON Master.SPName = DRCopy.SPName AND Master.id = DRCopy.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @SRECopy AS SRECopy ON Master.SPName = SRECopy.SPName AND Master.id = SRECopy.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     @DashCopy AS DashCopy ON Master.SPName = DashCopy.SPName AND Master.id = DashCopy.id
                     WHERE Master.id = @sp
RETURN 
END
GO
```

The call i make is:

```
USE [CommServ]
GO
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StoragePolicyCopies] (5)
GO
```

Comment: Why can't you use a Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a quick shot. You can replace the complete function to one single `SELECT` using a `CTE`.

```
;WITH DashCopy AS(
    SELECT archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS DashCopyName, archGroup.id
    FROM commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash 
        ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
    WHERE (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_Dash_Copy%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')
), DRCopy AS(
    SELECT archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS DRCopyName, archGroup.id
    FROM commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash 
        ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
    WHERE (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_DR%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')
), SRECopy AS(
    SELECT archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS SRECopyName, archGroup.id
    FROM commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash 
        ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
    WHERE (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_Recover%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')
), TapeCopy AS(
    SELECT archGroup.name AS SPName, archGroupCopy_Dash.name AS TapeCopyName, archGroup.id
    FROM commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN commserv.dbo.archGroupCopy AS archGroupCopy_Dash 
        ON archGroup.id = archGroupCopy_Dash.archGroupId
    WHERE (archGroupCopy_Dash.name LIKE '%_Monthly_Tape%') AND (archGroup.name NOT LIKE '%Global%')
), Master AS(
    SELECT name AS SPName, id
    FROM commserv.dbo.archGroup AS archGroup
    WHERE flags = 36 AND name NOT LIKE '%SEED%' AND name NOT LIKE '%ICO%'
)
SELECT        Master.id, Master.SPName, DashCopyName, SRECopyName, TapeCopyName, DRCopyName
FROM            Master 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TapeCopy 
    ON Master.SPName = TapeCopy.SPName AND Master.id = TapeCopy.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DRCopy 
    ON Master.SPName = DRCopy.SPName AND Master.id = DRCopy.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SRECopy 
    ON Master.SPName = SRECopy.SPName AND Master.id = SRECopy.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DashCopy 
    ON Master.SPName = DashCopy.SPName AND Master.id = DashCopy.id
WHERE Master.id = 5
```

It should do exactly the same.

But by the way, if it's possible for you and if your tables are a bit bigger. I would suggest to convert it in a procedure with multiple steps.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Bang on the money with this one!! CTE was the way forward, i don't need to create a procedure in our database which i was trying to avoid i also tried using table variables at the beginning of all this but they don't work outside of SQL. But this i can call this outside of SQL remotely and it works a treat. There is always an easy and a hard way to skin a cat, this way is much easier! Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear that this helps you. :-)